# java: why main thread waits for child thread to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple java program. A main thread (`main()`) is created and starts another thread `t`.

```
class T extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Inside thread");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new T();
        t.start();
        //t.join();
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
end
Inside thread
Inside thread
Inside thread
....
....
```

It infinitely prints **Inside thread**. I am not waiting for child thread in main thread using join(). Shouldn't main thread exit after printing **end**?

**Update:**

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single
>   non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some
>   designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute
>   threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security    manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by    returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception 
>     that propagates beyond the run method.

I found the reason. The second point clarified it. I was in assumption that all child thread will terminates after main thread exits (I was wrong) and JVM should shutdown.

Comment: What makes you think the main thread didn't exit?

Comment: It was a silly mistake :( @DavidSchwartz

Comment: I should have asked why JVM instead of main thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main thread *has* exited. It's the other thread that's still alive.

Comment: This can be made obvious by adding Thread.sleep(1000) after the print statement in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The thread you made is asynchronous from the `main` method. Therefore, there are two processes happening after calling `t.start()`. And once `main` ends, the main process is done, but thread t is still going on.

To better visualize this, use a boolean variable in the condition of your thread's while loop instead of `true` to make it so that the thread only prints 5 times.

```
class T extends Thread{
    int count;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count < 5){
            System.out.println("Inside thread");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that a thread won't stop itself if there is no way to terminate it. The main method ending will not terminate a thread.

Answer (score 0):

The commented method `t.join()` is exactly what is needed for the thread to wait for the end of the caller thread. See the Thread javadoc for more details

Answer (score 0):

The below code will run forever. please fix your while loop control logic

```
while (true) {
System.out.println("Inside thread");
}
```